# Linking to a Local Page from a Local Sever

Tags: html, pug, ejs

I've previously explained that I was trying to link a ejs page to a jade-based app. Then after many failed attempts I tried to convert that page to Jade and still ended up with a truckload of errors. Finally, I thought about simply putting a HTML Link that would redirect me to that ejs page on click.

What I fail to understand though, is why Firefox has no problems displaying the page when I directly put its path in the browser:

```
file:///home/ghanem/Documents/Project/views/account/el/el.ejs
```

But when I try to access it from my app through a simple code, it doesn't redirect me to the same very page:

```
<a href="file:///home/ghanem/Documents/Project/views/account/el/el.ejs">My Stubborn Link</a>
```

I should also point out that I've already set security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy to false in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

> What I fail to understand though, is why Firefox has no problems displaying the page when I directly put its path in the browser

Because it trusts you

> But when I try to access it from my app through a simple code

Your app is "just another website" as far as Firefox is concerned. It doesn't trust it.

> I should also point out that I've already set security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy to false in Firefox.

That lets XMLHttpRequest access `file://` URLs **providing** the document it is running in was loaded from a `file://` URL.

---

See [mozillaZine: Links to local pages do not work](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_don't_work).

```
user_pref("capability.policy.policynames", "localfilelinks");
user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.sites", "http://localhost:7896");
user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.checkloaduri.enabled", "allAccess");
```

Comment: Thanks for your great response. I have already added those lines in the prefs.js file, and yet when I click the html link it doesn't take me anywhere. It's really strange.